# Add CMS static block after add to cart

Tags: magento-1.9, addtocart, cms-block

I've been trying to add a static block to individual product pages, below the add to cart button, using "Product > Design > Custom Layout Update".

I've tried various versions of the code below, but without any success.

```
<reference name="content">
<block type="cms/block" name="wetsuits" before="product.info.addtocart">
    <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>wetsuits</block_id></action>
</block>  
</reference>
```

I'm using 1.9.1.0, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you see this this block anywhere on product page? If this CMS block exists, you should see it, but not 'below add to cart' button.

Comment: Yes, it does show on the page. But always above or below the "content" area. I did, at one time, have it working for placing special messages for certain brands, but that may have been on 1.7? However, I can't remember the old code I used then to make it work and the magento forum that used to exist is now gone, so I can't find those old posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change reference name to 'product.info':

```
<reference name="product.info">
    <block type="cms/block" name="wetsuits" before="product.info.addtocart">
        <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>wetsuits</block_id></action>
    </block>  
</reference>
```

And then add to `catalog/product/view.phtml` file in your template this code:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('wetsuits'); ?>
```

Comment: Excellent, this works very well and doesn't show unless the item has the Layout Update code - perfect!